# resignFirstResponder fails to dismiss my custom keyboard on iPad. Why?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uiresponder

I've created a custom keyboard and used the inputView property to associate it with a UITextField. When the "dismiss" button on my custom keyboard is pressed, I call resignFirstReponder on my text field.

Before you dismiss this as another IB outlet issue, it's not. The text field pointer is valid, and in fact after calling resignFirstResponder, the caret disappears, which proves that resignFirstResponder is in fact working. It's just that my custom keyboard isn't hiding itself. Any idea why?

Do I need to do anything special on the custom keyboard to make it hide itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[textField endEditing:YES];
```

It forces the textField to hide it's keyboard, but I'm not 100% sure it works for custom keyboards too. Give it a try :)!

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't seem to fix it. Could my custom keyboard be implemented incorrectly? It is implemented as a standard UIViewController. Do I need to do anything special to make the system treat it as a keyboard perhaps?

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure it has to be an UIView though, but that doesn't cause *this* problem... Anyway, Apple highly discourages the use of an custom keyboard (since it *really* disturb the users' UI-experience), so... are you sure you need a custom keyboard?

Comment: Apple discourages the use of custom keyboards?? They do it all over the place -- check out Numbers. There are several custom keyboards in that app. In any case, I decided to dump the custom keyboard and go with a standard numeric keyboard, though I do think it takes away from the overall UX.